# Chrome display issues with JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am using Jquery and the toggle method to display some html. This works perfectly in all browsers except Chrome (using **Chrome 10**). With chrome the elements that are toggled expand the page briefly and then go back into place.

I have tried setting widths on some of those elements, but it doesn't have any affect.

**Setup in JSFiddle**

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJHER/6/)

Comment: Can we see some code? Possibly the site, or something in jsfiddle?

Comment: 1. no code = no answer; 2. update to Chrome 10.

Comment: Needs your jQuery and CSS... Why not link to a page with the problem?

Comment: because it's not public. It's on local intranet. The html is all there, as well as the css. For jquery I used a simple toggle. See updated code. There is nothing else left to show...

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 9, http://jsfiddle.net/tzCJ8/

Comment: I guess this is a problem caused by something else in the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason you repeated the script in the html and in the js:
The click was being run twice due to it being in two places! :-)
here is the updated fiddle that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbmzP/

change the css to (on 1st line):

```
.poll { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 331px !important;}
```

This fixes the stretching on the animation of the toggle

Comment: Thanks for fixing the script thing. But chrome does not work. When you click on login notice the border expand?

Comment: thats is an implementation of jquery. jquery does that, there is not much you can do to contril it aside from putting in your css: `width: someNumber !important` which might work

Comment: ah... Seems strange that chrome is the only browser that has a problem with this.

Comment: browsers are weird, what can i tell ya? :-)  :-P